# ATMEGA328P reset circuit, not pulling down fully

Tags: avr, atmega, reset, atmega328p

Attached is the schematic of a reset circuit.  When I press the reset button, the voltage on the reset pin is 2.5 V.  Rmoving R13 naturally solves the issue, but I'm unclear as to why the configuration doesn't work.

I assumed that with a 10 kΩ pull-up and 300 Ω pull-down, the reset pin would be 0.2 V.

Is it perhaps the zener diode that's causing my circuit to fail?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to follow [this](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-F626284A-58F0-4C25-A6F3-0EA5054F3E2B-en-US-6/index.html?GUID-B80B25FF-E9D7-4766-B562-DA197B8B938C) reset pin connection recommendation:

[image]

The recommendation according to the diagram above is to add an ESD protection diode.

But instead you're using a Zener diode. When doing so, you should connect to cathode of the Zener diode to the RESET pin, and the anode to GND.

Microchip Online Docs:

- [Connection of RESET Pin on AVR Devices](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-F626284A-58F0-4C25-A6F3-0EA5054F3E2B-en-US-6/index.html?GUID-B80B25FF-E9D7-4766-B562-DA197B8B938C)
- [External RESET Switch](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-F626284A-58F0-4C25-A6F3-0EA5054F3E2B-en-US-6/index.html?GUID-0EE45B63-FF7B-4211-B464-C2C6B66F92C1)

Comment: This answer is what you want to try. The zener diode would be in addition to the diode shown in the schematic. I think that’s the confusion by the OP. Microchip refers to a zener but doesn’t show how it would be connected. Why do you need a zener? Do you have concerns about high voltage on this line? Note that the answer’s second link does in fact recommend your R13, which should be included.

Comment: The circuit I was following was the recommendations from microchip, I must have misread the ESD protection diode for the zener.

Answer (score 2):

- Zener diode can be leaky, thus add pull-up current.
- Button can have big resistance in pushed state.
- Resistors can have wrong value or be defective.

Try to measure voltage on reset pin to see what actually happens. According to datasheet, reset threshold voltage can be as low as 0,2 Vcc.

AVR appnote recommends capacitor on reset pin to be about 1000 pF, with big cap you probably will not be able to program it.

Comment: This is unlikely the correct answer. Button resistances so large that it won’t work is possible, but unlikely. Resistors being defective is very unlikely. 100nF capacitors are commonly used in this application. The diode is almost certainly the problem and should be looked at first.